# Replacing static site with Django/Serving static files with mod_wsgi

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi

I have an existing static website that is served via apache. I wanted to add dynamic features to that site so I created a Django app that lives in a subfolder (ie. `/django-site/`). I have this configured like this:

```
    WSGIDaemonProcess django_site processes=5 threads=5 user=user group=group python-home=path/to/virtualenv
    WSGIScriptAlias /django-site /var/www/django_site/wsgi.py
    <Location /django-site>
    WSGIProcessGroup group
    </Location>
```

But now I would like to replace certain pages that were originally static pages in the root directory. But I don't want to replace all of the static pages.

I know that [Django recommends](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/) putting your static files in a subdirectory like `/media` or `/static` and Django configured to be the root directory but since I have a long legacy of these static pages being in the root directory and external links to these pages I don't want to change that.

Is there a recommended way to replace these static pages with a dynamic ones?

Here are a few ideas that I have thought of:

1. Use `ProxyPass` to replace pages one at a time
2. Redirect static pages to dynamic versions, change internal links to new dynamic version
3. Move dynamic site to root, and use something like [whitenoise](http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/) to serve those files

Comment: 4) Implement the dynamic features using modern client-side scripting techniques and make Django serve the data via an API (REST, Graphene, ...),

Comment: Are there a lot of pages? You may serve them from django by configuring all the necessary URLs and render them from Django as HttpResponses. 
You can serve static files via nginx or via app `django.contrib.staticfiles`
Though, it require quite a work for migration...

Comment: @EgorWexler - there are unfortunately thousands of pages that need to continue to exist in that form (static html pages) served from the root (ie. `domain/page.html` `domain/page2.html`). I only need to migrate some of them to be dynamic pages though. That's where I'm stuck on what the best approach is

Comment: @DHamrick, maybe you can give a certain fixed path to dynamic URLs. E.g. domain/dynamic/<the page>. So for root, there will be no Django-related stuff.

Comment: @EgorWexler - that's what I have now. All the dynamic pages under a certain fixed path. But now I would like to replace a couple of the static pages with dynamic ones but keep the same urls under the root directory.

Comment: I believe that the canonical way of doing this is to use mod_rewrite, as an answer suggests.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Apache mod_rewrite to keep the existing links functional. The [documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/remapping.html#static-to-dynamic) suggests this:

> Description:
> How can we transform a static page foo.html into a dynamic variant foo.cgi in a seamless way, i.e. without notice by the browser/user.

> Solution:
> We just rewrite the URL to the CGI-script and force the handler to be cgi-script so that it is executed as a CGI program. This way a request to /~quux/foo.html internally leads to the invocation of /~quux/foo.cgi.

```
RewriteEngine  on
RewriteBase    "/~quux/"
RewriteRule    "^foo\.html$"  "foo.cgi"  [H=cgi-script]
```